# How to programatically update Azure Storage firewall settings

Tags: azure, azure-storage, firewall, rest

I am using Azure Storage, and it allows to control access by managing "Firewall and Virtual Network" settings from the Azure portal.
Is there a way to do the same via API? I did some documentation search but could not find APIs which can do this.
Any pointer around this will be helpful.

Comment: Any preference for programming language?

Comment: Welcome to https://stackoverflow.com/. For any specific problem you are having please include a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example. Please also read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask. Make sure that your questions are specific and not overly broad, see also https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic. Also, be sure to take the https://stackoverflow.com/tour (you get a badge!).

Comment: You have all the documentation for Azure Storage here including different ways so use it: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/

Comment: Nodejs would be great, but if you can point to the API, then I can manage :)

Comment: @DanielBjörk Thanks for the docs, But I found it difficult to find the information I am looking for in that

Comment: @Jakao Start with reading how to ask a question then its easier to get proper help. Your question does not meet the quality of a question to fit in on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to update Azure Storage Firewall via API, you want to use the following Rest API to implement it. For more details, please refer to [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storagerp/storageaccounts/update)

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}?api-version=2019-06-01

Authorization: Bearer <access token>

{
  "properties": {
    "networkAcls": {
      "bypass": "string",
      "virtualNetworkRules": [
        {
          "id": "string",
          "action": "Allow",
          "state": "string"
        }
      ],
      "ipRules": [
        {
          "value": "string",
          "action": "Allow"
        }
      ],
      "defaultAction": "string"
     }
  }
}
```

For example

1. Create a service principal and assign `Contributor` role to the sp

```
az login
# create sp and assign Contributor to the sp at the subscription level
az ad sp create-for-rbac -n "your service principal name"
```

2. Get Token

```
POST https://login.microsoftonline.com/<tenant id>/oauth2/v2.0/token
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

grant_type=client_credentials
&scope=https://management.azure.com/.default
&client_id=<sp appId>
&client_secret=<sp password>
```

3. Test (I update the account's firewall to allow some IP and AzureServices to access storage).

```
PATCH https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts/{accountName}?api-version=2019-06-01

Authorization: Bearer <access token>

{
  "properties": {
        "networkAcls": {
            "bypass": "AzureServices",
            "virtualNetworkRules": [],
            "ipRules": [
                {
                    "value": "167.220.255.0/24",
                    "action": "Allow"
                }
            ],
            "defaultAction": "Deny"
        }
   }
}
```

[image: result]

Answer (score 0):

I Use a PowerShell script to do this

```
# Set resource group & storage account
$rg='my_resource_group'
$stor_acc='my_storage_account'

# Get current IP from Public API
$ipGetCommand = 'https://api.ipify.org'
$webclient = New-Object System.Net.WebClient
$public_ip = $webclient.DownloadString($ipGetCommand)

# Add Public IP to FW rules
Add-AzStorageAccountNetworkRule -ResourceGroupName $rg -AccountName $stor_acc -IPAddressOrRange $public_ip
```

Obviously, its a quick & dirty example. You'd probably want to check you get an IP back & check the API is running but you get the gist... and don't forget anyone running this will still need permissions to add firewall rules.